# Viber for macOS and the location of ViberDownloads folder

Tags: folders

Is there a way to set the location of ViberDownloads folder for the Viber desktop application for macOS?

Comment: https://www.techjunkie.com/change-downloads-folder-mac/ [I can't actually read it because they have an unacceptable cookie policy]

Comment: It does not give HowTo for Viber. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In Telegram, the dl folder is editable. Adobe apps also have it in settings. WhatsApp asks every time. This heavily depends on the specific app.